# How do I fix my machine after purging ca-certificates?

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, postfix, tty

I have done a very silly thing by running the following command.

```
sudo apt-get purge postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

This has left my machine without a network connection of any kind and without access to peripherals.

When I power up I get put into a TTY session. From here I have tried `apt` to reinstall the packages but can't because I have no access to the web or an external drive.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you download the debs manually on another computer, transfer via USB and install them?

Comment: Sadly not. I've tried. But purging the certificates seems to have blocked all peripherals including USB sticks.

Comment: I suspect the USB stick does work, but doesn't automount without the help of the desktop environment helping you. It's likely possible to mount it manually. If you plug a stick in and then run `lsblk`, you'll probably see the device show up as something like `/dev/sdb1` or similar. You may be able to manually mount it with `mkdir ~/usb` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ~/usb`. Making sure to get the device name right

Comment: Aha! Yes, that works. Thank you! But my next question is, what should I copy accross? I've tried copying `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` but that doesn't do the job.

Comment: When I look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` I see the result of my purge command. 
`Purge: kerneloops:amd64 (0.12+git20140509-6ubuntu5), python3-nbclient:and64 (0.5.6-2) ...`
The list is long and all entries end `amd64`.

Comment: I would go to packages.ubuntu.com and search for the packages - there's filters for releases, or you can just put the package name in the url like packages.ubuntu.com/ca-certificates and then download the amd64 deb from whichever mirror you like.

Comment: Here, I made a quick video showing you how to find and download the debs. https://youtu.be/48iY1Po0uUw

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much. That is far beyond the call of duty. I'm now back into my system. Data is safe and I'm a happy man. I have have some missing apps but I'm sure I can sort those out myself. I really can't thank you enough @popey.

Comment: Yay! Happy days, I'll turn my comments into an answer so it's easier to find. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On another computer, I would go to packages.ubuntu.com and search for the packages - there's filters for releases, or you can just put the package name in the url like packages.ubuntu.com/ca-certificates and then download the amd64 deb from whichever mirror you like.

Once you have downloaded them all, put them on a USB stick, and take that to the broken computer. If you're stuck in a TTY it might not automount the USB stick. All is not lost, however.

If you plug a stick in and then run `lsblk`, you'll probably see the device show up as something like `/dev/sdb1` or similar. You may be able to manually mount it with `mkdir ~/usb` then sudo mount `/dev/sdb1 ~/usb`. Making sure to get the device name right

I made a quick video showing you how to find and download the debs. https://youtu.be/48iY1Po0uUw